# Angular2 passing variables between component and service

Tags: angular

I am trying to better understand passing values between a component and a service in Angular 2.

My **main.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MainService {
    private mainSource = new Subject<boolean>();
    main$ = this.mainSource.asObservable();

    private textSource = new Subject<string>();
    text$ = this.textSource.asObservable();

    setWorking(isWorking:boolean){
        this.mainSource.next(isWorking);
    }

    setTexting(isTexting:string){
        this.textSource.next(isTexting);
    }
}
```

My **app.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MainService } from './main.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    private subscription: Subscription;
    private textres: string;
    constructor(private mainService: MainService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.subscription = this.mainService.main$.subscribe(isWorking =>{
            if (isWorking){this.mainService.setTexting("Yeah");}
        });
        this.mainService.setWorking(true);
        this.textres = this.mainService.setTexting;
    }

}
```

I have a `mainSource`, which is a boolean, and is subscribed by my component. This works well. Now, I would like to pass string values in between my component and service through `textSource`.

During Init I have set the value of `setTexting('Yeah')` but I do not know how to call it in my component's `textres`.

How might I acquire the value of `this.mainService.setTexting`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code to access the value of setTexting would be

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    private subscription: Subscription;
    private textres: string;
    constructor(private mainService: MainService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.subscription = this.mainService.main$.subscribe(isWorking =>{
            if (isWorking){this.mainService.setTexting("Yeah");}
        });
        this.mainService.setWorking(true);

      // access to setTexting value 
      this.mainService.text$.subscribe(value =>{
            this.textres= value;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something. For whatever reason your code does not do anything.

Comment: Nvm. Got it. I moved setWorking to the bottom.

Comment: can you make MainService line var text$ = function(){ return this.textSource;}  and try